# Center align table grob to x-axis label

Tags: r

I stole the example below (original found http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/81-ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/#align-plot-panels). The output center aligns the table within the figure, but I want to center align the table to the x-axis label of the plot above. What is the easiest way to do this?

```
library("ggpubr")
library("grid")
library("gridExtra")
# Density plot of "Sepal.Length"
#::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
density.p <- ggdensity(iris, x = "Sepal.Length", 
                       fill = "Species", palette = "jco")
# Draw the summary table of Sepal.Length
#::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
# Compute descriptive statistics by groups
stable <- desc_statby(iris, measure.var = "Sepal.Length",
                      grps = "Species")
stable <- stable[, c("Species", "length", "mean", "sd")]
# Summary table plot, medium orange theme
stable.p <- ggtexttable(stable, rows = NULL, 
                        theme = ttheme("mOrange"))
p <- arrangeGrob(density.p, stable.p, 
                 ncol = 1,
                 heights = c(2, 1))
grid.draw(p)
```

This is the output.

[image]

This is the output I would like (table shifted to right to align with x axis label).
[image]

Comment: Could you add the output you expect, using the graph and the desired position of the elements?

Comment: Maybe the graph by hand?

Comment: Added, and I would like to automate this as I would need to generate multiple figures like this.

Comment: If I understand correctly, you only want to add some space to the right of the table, is that correct?

Comment: Yes, but that space is determined by the position of the x-axis.

Comment: I have added some options, hope any of them can help you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with `patchwork`:

```
library(patchwork)
#Code
G <- density.p/stable.p
```

Output:

[image]

Or this:

```
#Code 2
G <- density.p/(plot_spacer()+stable.p)
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: @user13589693 Always a pleasure helping. Yeah it is an improved package for merging plots! Pretty useful!